# send message textfield at the bottom of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

[image: see image here]

How can i add this send message textfield at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Could you provide the code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [Icon(Icons.face_outlined), Text("Message...")],
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: 1,
            ),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

You can edit the Icon and font settings based on your liking.

Answer (score 0):

On screen's `Scaffold` use`bottomNavigationBar:` and provide the `TextFiled` including the way you like to format it.

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: TextField(),//decorate
      body: ....
```

more about [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.used **Stack** widget for that refer `Stack` widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```
 Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: Stack(
      children: [
       //add your other widgets here
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
             child: Image.network(
                'https://tech.pelmorex.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/flutter.png'),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.tag_faces_sharp),
              hintText: 'message',
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]